# CAPL invalid type cast of uint32 to dword

Tags: capl

Please hear me out on this. Let `sysA` be a system variable (struct member) of type `Uint32` used to store a unique hexadecimal ID four bytes long.
In my CAPL script, I'd like to perform a check between this UUID and an integer I re-define by composition of four bytes coming from a message. I went with this approach:

```
variables
{
    dword uuid;
}

on message myMsg
{
    uuid = (this.byte(0)<<24) | (this.byte(1)<<16)| (this.byte(2)<<8) | this.byte(3);
    if (@sysA == uuid)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

this code triggers error, because of incompatible types `dword` and `Uint32`. I then tried casting `sysA` to `dword`: `invalid type cast`. I'm not sure why this would be the case **in the CAPL language**. According to the docs:

> byte (unsigned, 1 Byte)
>
> word (unsigned, 2 Byte)
>
> dword (unsigned, 4 Byte)
>
> int (signed, 2 Byte)
>
> long (signed, 4 Byte)
>
> int64 (signed, 8 Byte)
>
> qword (unsigned, 8 Byte)

I cannot type cast Uint32 system variables to `int`: `int i = 32768` is out of range and `int i = 32768LL` isn't valid. But `dword`, in this context, is strictly `unsigned int` of 4 bytes.

*What should I correctly use as type for my uuid, in this scenario, and why?*

Comment: I think `dword` as type for `uuid` is fine. Can you show the code where you have tried to explicitly cast `@sysA` to dword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code snippet too. You should have a try with defining the proper namespace also when you're trying to use system variables.

```
variables
{
  dword uuid;
}

on message * 
{
  uuid = ((this.byte(0) << 24) | (this.byte(1) << 16) | (this.byte(2) << 8) | (this.byte(3)));

  if ((dword)@namespace::sysA == uuid)
  {
    write ("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello vakesz, thanks for your feedback. Yes, most likely I forgot to report the namespace in the snippet, but you can't create a variable without namespace in CANoe. Did you try your code snippet? Does it work without error?

Comment: Hi, I did try to compile the code which I sent. It was compiling without a warning. But I did not try it in a real simulation. I used CANalyzer 10. namespace is the name of the namespace I defined for the system variable. You can check it by checking your variable what did you define as namespace to it.